# opening/closing database connection inside repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I have a repeater which grabs data from multiple tables in each iteration. Right now i'm opening the connection as soon as i enter the OnItemDataBound event and closing it before the event is complete. That means the connections is opened and closed more than 1000 times in my case. Is this the right way to do this? are there any other ways?

my code basically looks like this

```
 Protected Sub myRepeater_OnItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs)
    Try
        mycon.open()
        Dim RowView As DataRowView = e.Item.DataItem

        //fetch data from 5 different tables using the data from the datasource (dataset)

        mycon.close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: It really depends on the data you need. Is it possible for you to query all the data in your forms constructor and set the repeaters datasource with the results? Check the first example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx

Comment: that is not possible in this situation. the repeater is using a dataset as its datasource. i have to use the data provided to find relevant information inside 5 other tables.

Comment: Then I am afraid you may be boned. I would suggest pagenating your values so you only have to call maybe 100 queries per page.

Comment: You are correct, accessing a DB "more than 1000 times" per page is **very very bad**. Unless the "other data" is located on different SQL servers, there is almost certainly a way to retrieve all the data at once, without having to re-query the DB for each bound repeater item. Maybe give us some more information about your datasource and the expected SQL results?

Comment: i don't know any other way to explain the situation. but the results are as expected and it works just fine. as you mentioned the concern in accessing the db so many times. The five tables that i have to access are all on the same db but i've no control over the dataset that i am provided to be used as source.

Comment: Atar, just so you know, if you are responding to another user's comment, you need to include their @ name for them to be informed that a new response awaits them. It's pretty simple, just type the @ symbol and a helper window will show you a choice of who to respond to.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's good practise to open/close connection immediately in the smallest possible scope since you are not clocing the physical connection when you're using connection-pooling. You are just make the connection usable when you close it.

But apart from that, why do you use a connection at all in `ItemDataBound` which is raised **after** the repeater was already databound? The [`DataItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.dataitem.aspx) should contain all you need.  If you want to `DataBind` child controls like DropDownLists or nested repeaters, yes, that's the correct way (well, you should better encapsulate it in methods then).

And you should use [`using-statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) to dispose(close) connections:

```
Dim rowView As DataRowView = e.Item.DataItem
Dim someDropDown = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1"), DropDownList)
Using myCon = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Try
        mycon.Open()
        'databind the dropdown...'
    Catch ex As Exception
        'log exception'
    End Try
End Using
```

Comment: i am getting a dataset (data source for the repeater) from a separate location and using the data inside the datatable i have to find relevant data in 5 different tables and display it using the repeater.